# Explanation of the parts of a bubble sort and a selection sort

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm studying for a final and I'm having some difficulty understanding what each line of the codes below do. I understand how each sort works in theory, but, I'm having issues understanding how the code accomplishes the task at hand. I haven't been able to find a clear explanation where I have looked. Can someone please go through each of the functions below and comment with what role each bit plays? If I need to include the full programs these are a part of please let me know. I've omitted them due to their excessive length. Thanks in advance!

```
void SelectionSort(int numbers[], int array_size) {
for (int i = array_size - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    int startIndex = 0; //initialization of start index
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)  //i don't understand this line or the next two
        if (numbers[j] > numbers[startIndex])
            startIndex = j;

    int tempIndex = numbers[startIndex]; // these three lines use a temp variable to swap
    numbers[startIndex] = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = tempIndex;
}

return;
}

void BubbleSort(int numbers[], int array_size) {
for (int outer = (array_size - 1); outer >= 0; outer--) // this line I vaguely understand (need clarification)
    for (int inner = 0; inner < outer; inner++) /* this line I vaguely understand (need clarification)*/
        if (numbers[inner] < numbers[inner + 1]) /*this compares the two values*/ { 
            int tempIndex = numbers[inner]; /* these three lines use a temp variable to swap the value in each location if the above criteria is met*/
            numbers[inner] = numbers[inner + 1];
            numbers[inner + 1] = tempIndex;
        }
return;
}
```

Comment: Narrow down your question to a few lines of code. If you are asking for a full explanation of *each* line , you're at the wrong place.

Comment: You say that you understand how each sort works in theory, so try to implement the sort in pseudo code, then try to match your pseudocode to this code. or put in your own comments of what you think each line does, then think about why it should be doign that? if you find that it shouldnt, check again to see that it really is doing what you think it is doing

Comment: I added comments as to what I think each bit does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selection Sort:
The selection sort starts in the outer loop with the last value in the array. It then goes through the whole array with the inner loop and finds the largest value, assigning its index to the startIndex variable. It then replaces the last value, index i, with this startIndex value which is the largest in the array. It then repeats this process for all values in the array. Notice that in the inner loop, j<=i makes it slightly more efficient than j<=array_size-1. This is because, once the last index is assigned during the first iteration of the outer loop as the largest variable, nothing needs to be tested against that as everything left will be smaller than it. As i gets smaller and smaller, all the indexes above it have already been assigned the largest values in ascending order.

Bubble Sort:
The outer for loop takes the last value in the array and then iterates down to the first value. For each iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop is testing each pair of numbers, starting from the first and second, then going up until it reaches the index that the outer loop is at and the index at one less than that. For each iteration of the inner loop, the pair is being compared and if the value at the lesser index is smaller, it will switch with the value one index above it (so it is sorting in ascending order). The outer loop is really unnecessary, it just makes the loop more efficient. The idea behind it is that once the first iteration of the inner loop has run, the last value has to be the largest, which is what it should be, so that can then be ignored when running the sort for each resultant iteration. It continues this process until it gets to the last pair and sorts them accordingly.

Comment: I appreciate your thorough explanation. It makes sense to me now. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. I actually had never considered that outer loop as a way of making sorts more efficient so thanks for that. :)